# Custom generator to have enum fields as Strings using OpenAPI codegen

Tags: java, openapi-generator

I'm attempting to write a custom generator that replaces enum type fields with String.

This is what I came up with:

```java
public class CustomGenerator extends JavaClientCodegen {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, ModelsMap> postProcessAllModels(Map<String, ModelsMap> objs) {
        objs.forEach((String modelName, Object properties) -> {

            Map<String, Object> modelProperties = (Map<String, Object>) properties;
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> models = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>) modelProperties.get("models");

            models.stream()
                .map(map -> map.get("model"))
                .forEach(prop -> removeEnumsFromModel((CodegenModel) prop));
        });

        return super.postProcessAllModels(objs);
    }

    private void removeEnumsFromModel(CodegenModel model) {
        if (model.hasEnums) {
            model.allVars.forEach(this::removeEnumFromVar);
            model.hasEnums = model.allVars.stream()
                .anyMatch(property -> property.isEnum);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void removeEnumFromVar(CodegenProperty property) {
        if (property.isEnum) {
            property.datatypeWithEnum = "String";
            property.isEnum = false;
            property.isInnerEnum = false;
            property.isEnumRef = false;
            property._enum = null;
            property.allowableValues = null;
            property.enumName = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "cg";
    }
}
```

This is my configuration:

```
def openApiGeneratorConfig = {
    classpath configurations.openApiGenerator
    mainClass = 'org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator'
    args 'generate'
    args '-g', 'dev.rifaii.CustomGenerator'
    args '-o', "$projectDir"
    args '-t', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/openapi-config/templates"
    args "--additional-properties",
            "library=feign," +
                    "dateLibrary=java8," +
                    "useBeanValidation=false," +
                    "performBeanValidation=false," +
                    "implicitHeaders=true"
}
```

I'm using 'org.openapitools:openapi-generator-cli:6.6.0' dependency

However, the generate models still have enum fields, I went through debugger and verified that the enum field types are being set to String but this is not reflected in generated code.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in removeEnumsFromModel method, It

```java
model.vars.forEach(this::removeEnumFromVar)
```

instead of

```java
model.allVars.forEach(this::removeEnumFromVar)
```